# Capture Keyboard and mouse event thorugh java library on any tools

Tags: java, events

I want to capture the keyboard and mouse click event on my window everywhere suppose I have opened browser or opened notepad or some other tools, it should not be effected. I know to do one way this with the batch file but I am trying to do this thruogh java libraries. I tried with AWT and swing but they can only capture within their frame.

Please suggest me approach for captuering keyboard and mouse event through java. Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Look at JFrame#getGlassPane()

Comment: They are only working on the frame for which we have designed through swing or awt, I tried to do this with eventListener.

Comment: Which OS are you considering - Windows?

Answer (score 0):

This is problematic the moment you want to run it on different platforms. For Windows, you would need to use Java Native Interface directly to access dll's, or use ready libraries such as [this](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna).

These listeners in general are not trivial to implement, but there are some good examples in test sections of linked gitpage.